# ASP.NET Web API File saved as "BodyPart_3ded2bfb-40be-4183-b789-9301f93e90af"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, http, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I'm uploading files using the ASP.NET Web API. I've done this before the RC but for some reason the file is being saved as "BodyPart_3ded2bfb-40be-4183-b789-9301f93e90af" instead of the file name. The filename variable below returns this bodypart string too instead of the file name. I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Client code:

```
function upload() {
    $("#divResult").html("Uploading...");
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/files/uploadfile?folder=' + $('#ddlFolders').val(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divResult").html(data);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
};
```

Controller:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile([FromUri]string folder)
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        // Save file
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files"));
        Task<IEnumerable<HttpContent>> task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        return task.ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(contents =>
        {
            string filename = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
          {
              Content = new StringContent(string.Format("File saved in {0}.", folder))
          };

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The files are looking like:

[image]

Comment: I wrote up my complete example here: http://rivdiv.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/uploading-a-file-using-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That was a concious change we made -- it was considered a security risk to take the file name provided in the Content-Disposition header field and so instead we now compute a file name which is what you are seeing.

If you want to control the server local file name yourself then you can derive from MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and override GetLocalFileName to provide whatever name you want. Note though that there may be security considerations doing so.

Hope this helps,

Henrik

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I then save the actual file correctly? Right now it's of "File" data type with no extension at all and can't be opened.

Comment: I found a work-around for now - to use File.Move and add the correct extension by using *provider.BodyPartFileNames.FirstOrDefault().Key.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"')* to get the original file name. This feels a bit backwards though. I'd appreciate any enlightenment.Thanks.

Comment: public class FormDataStreamer : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
        public FormDataStreamer(string rootPath) : base(rootPath) { }

        public FormDataStreamer(string rootPath, int bufferSize) : base(rootPath, bufferSize) { }

        public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            var srcFileName = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
            return Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(srcFileName);
        }
    }

Comment: Hi Henrik I'm curious, could you elaborate a bit on the security considerations using a custom MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and overwriting GetLocalFileName?

Answer (score 19):

I updated the code for the tutorial to make it work with ASP.NET Web API RC. Indeed, as Henrik mentioned Content-Disposition is no longer used a file name. See the source files at the bottom of the post - http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/html5-drag-and-drop-asynchronous-multi-file-upload-with-asp-net-webapi/

Please note, that there are further changes to MultipartFormDataStreamProvider that didn't make the cut to the RC, so it's now even more flexible. Henrik blogged about those here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/27/asp-net-web-api-updates-april-27.aspx.

**EDIT:** I have blogged about new and improved way of uploading files in Web API RTM, so that should hopefully help gets things organized - http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

Comment: Thanx, your example is easy to read and follow. I had written my own using the beta code and was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to do it in the RC.

Comment: Thank you Filip. So I assume the correct way *is* to get the original file from the key and then moving/renaming the file. Didn't come across any Web API articles that had this particular RC change specified, glad I put this question out there. Thanks.

Comment: This is just beautiful. Works like a charm!

Comment: Than you so much for this really appreciate it had no clue this was the case

Answer (score 14):

Here, this work for me

**In API Controller**

```
// We implement MultipartFormDataStreamProvider to override the filename of File which
// will be stored on server, or else the default name will be of the format like Body-
// Part_{GUID}. In the following implementation we simply get the FileName from 
// ContentDisposition Header of the Request Body.
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then

```
 string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");       
 CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
```

Thanks,