# Posting ByteArray from Knockout.js to a Web Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, post, knockout.js

I'm very new to KnockoutJS, and I dig it so far, but try as I might I couldn't find this info anywhere so I am hoping the community can help! In my View I have the following data-binding on a file input:

```
 <input type="file" data-bind="value: ImageToUpload"/>
 <button data-bind="click: $root.saveImage">Upload</button>
```

This is part of a list in a "foreach" div, so the variable "ImageToUpload" corresponds to a property on an object from that list.

In my ViewModel the Upload button calls saveImage() and I call the web service and pass the form data to a .aspx page:

```
self.saveImage = function (MyObject, event) {

    $.post("Service.aspx", MyObject,  function (returnedData) {

    });
}
```

The object passes to my service just fine and I can access all the form data as expected including the "ImageToUpload" variable... but here is where I am stuck:

1) The "ImageToUpload" is only a string representing the name of the file I uploaded and is not a ByteArray. How do I access the image file and not just the name?

2) Is there a better way to pass the ByteArray as a Stream or other format in the response header?

3) Is my technique totally off? Is there a better way to do this? My goal is to have a dynamic list of image "slots" that be uploaded to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inability to access local file contents was a fundamental limitation of JavaScript security sandbox. It was lifted with the introduction of [HTML5 file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), but, unfortunately, support is [far from universal](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). If your code needs to work in non-compliant browsers, your only option is to let the browser handle the traditional `multipart/form-data` upload. If, on the other hand, not supporting IE < 10 is fine for you, it is possible to use File API "the Knockout way" with custom bindings. Have a look at this example: http://khayrov.github.com/jsfiddle/knockout-fileapi (for some reason [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) breaks badly for me when I try to run this code in it). [Source code](https://github.com/khayrov/khayrov.github.com/tree/master/jsfiddle/knockout-fileapi) at Github.

Comment: I know this is oldish but if youre still around I have a question. How can I pass this arraybuffer back to an mvc controller?

Answer (score 6):

File uploads need to be handled in a special manner. They are generally not part of your model. Take a look at the following ApiController. Specialized classes such as the `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` are used to access the binary data that was submitted to the controller.

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public List<FileResult> UploadFile()
    {
        // Verify that this is an HTML Form file upload request
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        // Create a stream provider for setting up output streams
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider();

        // Read the MIME multipart content using the stream provider we just created.
        IEnumerable<HttpContent> bodyparts = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).Result;

        // The submitter field is the entity with a Content-Disposition header field with a "name" parameter with value "submitter"
        string submitter;
        if (!bodyparts.TryGetFormFieldValue("submitter", out submitter))
        {
            submitter = "unknown";
        }

        // Get a dictionary of local file names from stream provider.
        // The filename parameters provided in Content-Disposition header fields are the keys.
        // The local file names where the files are stored are the values.
        IDictionary<string, string> bodyPartFileNames = streamProvider.BodyPartFileNames;

        // Create response containing information about the stored files.
        return bodyPartFileNames.Select(kv =>
        {
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(kv.Value);
            return new FileResult
            {
                FileName = kv.Key,
                LocalPath = fileinfo.FullName,
                LastModifiedTime = fileinfo.LastWriteTimeUtc,
                Length = fileinfo.Length,
                Submitter = submitter
            };
        }).ToList();
    }

    private static bool TryGetFormFieldValue(IEnumerable<HttpContent> contents, string dispositionName, out string formFieldValue)
    {
        HttpContent content = contents.FirstDispositionNameOrDefault(dispositionName);
        if (content != null)
        {
            formFieldValue = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return true;
        }

        formFieldValue = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

An alternative solution that's a little less heavy on the code is to use `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter for your ApiController. `HttpPostedFileBase` is essentially a wrapper for a file that was uploaded through a form. I must add that using  `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` is preferred over `HttpPostedFileBase`, because the latter is part of the ASP.NET MVC framework. Remember, WebAPI technology can be used outside of ASP.NET MVC.

More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx and [ASP.NET Web API File saved as "BodyPart_3ded2bfb-40be-4183-b789-9301f93e90af"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970750/asp-net-web-api-file-saved-as-bodypart-3ded2bfb-40be-4183-b789-9301f93e90af)