# ASP.Net Web API - Get POSTed file synchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to **synchronously** process an uploaded file POSTed to a controller in the ASP.Net Web API?

I've tried the process Microsoft proposed [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2), and it works as described, but I'd like to return something other than a Task<> from the Controller method in order to match the rest of my RESTful API.

Basically, I'm wondering if there is there any way to make this work:

```
public MyMugshotClass PostNewMugshot(MugshotData data){
    //get the POSTed file from the mime/multipart stream <--can't figure this out
    //save the file somewhere
    //Update database with other data that was POSTed
    //return a response
}
```

Again, I have made the asynchronous example work but am hoping for a way to process the uploaded file before responding to the client.

Comment: When you `await` in an `async` ASP.NET method, you do not respond to the client. The client response is only sent out when all `async` operations complete. [Async doesn't change the HTTP protocol.](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var appData = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var folder = Path.Combine(appData, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(folder);
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        if (result.FileData.Count < 1)
        {
            // no files were uploaded at all
            // TODO: here you could return an error message to the client if you want
        }

        // at this stage all files that were uploaded by the user will be
        // stored inside the folder we specified without us needing to do
        // any additional steps

        // we can now read some additional FormData
        string caption = result.FormData["caption"];

        // TODO: update your database with the other data that was posted

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "thanks for uploading");
    }
}
```

You might notice that the uploaded files are stored inside the specified folder with names that might look like this: `BodyPart_beddf4a5-04c9-4376-974e-4e32952426ab`. That's a [deliberate choice that the Web API team made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10972291/29407) that you could override if you want.

Comment: How do you save the file with an appropriate extension so they can be correctly read? How do you know how to open a file when it has no extension. This seems like bad design.

Comment: @jaffa, normally I store the mime type and physical location of the file in my backend. Then it doesn't really matter the physical name of the file on the disk. I already have this information when needed.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov hi, so you store in the DB the physicial location and mime type of the file uploaded? Then you map it to the physicial BodayPart_.... name on App Data?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  This handles the request asynchronously.  The original question was for synchronous processing.

Comment: The poster asked for handling the file upload synchonously, this code uses async.

Comment: how is this synchronously?

Comment: Like the original poster, I want my client to get a response from the server when the operation has completed successfully. This doesn't achieve that.