# Getting the file name of uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

When I use the following code, the file is properly uploaded in the `uploadPath`, but the `GetLocalFileName` method returns the wrong `BodyPart` name.

The guid in the file name (ex: `BodyPart_f4a1e725-0194-4bda-a666-b6ffea7b0618`) will be some other guid that isn't the file just uploaded.

I am trying to get the file name of the uploaded file.

```
private string lastUploadFileName

public async Task AsyncReceive(HttpRequestMessage incomingRequest)
{
    request = incomingRequest;
    streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);
    var uploadTask = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

    await uploadTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error uploading file.");

        }
    });

    lastUploadFileName = streamProvider.GetLocalFileName(
        request.Content.Headers);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970750/asp-net-web-api-file-saved-as-bodypart-3ded2bfb-40be-4183-b789-9301f93e90af

Comment: Indeed. Is there a way to delete my question ?

Comment: I added a vote too close.